# extract the retrieved date to month & day in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a (date time) stored in database in this format 2011-10-12 02:01:24

when retrieve this date i want to extract that date so i can show the day or month without the other date value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this with this code:

in my view

```
    <?php 
    $date_of_post = $r->date_nw;    
    $date = $date_of_post; // 6 october 2011 2:28 pm
    $stamp = strtotime($date); // outputs 1307708880
    ?>

    <?php echo date("d", $stamp); ?> // it prints out the day only
    <?php echo date("M", $stamp); ?> // it prints out the Month only like (Oct)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [date & time functions of MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html) or PHP functions like [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime).

For instance, with `strtotime()`:

```
$timestamp = strtotime('2011-10-12 02:01:24');

echo 'The month is '.date('F', $timestamp).' and the day number is '.date('d', $timestamp);
```

Will outputs:

`The month is October and the day number is 12`

Comment: here is the code i use:


$date_of_post = $r->date_nw;
   $month = MONTHNAME('$date_of_post'); 
   $timestamp = strtotime('$date_of_post');
   echo 'The month is '.date('F', $timestamp).' and the day number is '.date('d', $timestamp); 

($r->date_nw;) this is the date retrieved from database, and it prints data when echo it


( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined function MONTHNAME() in E:\Files\Local machine\hi5tyle_ci\application\views\inner_page.php on line 31

Comment: You confuse MySQL and PHP functions. The simpler way to do what you want it's to get the date with MySQL, simply, and just apply the PHP `strtotime()` function on it.